# Getting Failure delivering result while transfering data between activities using sqlite database and a class

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am working on a tasks app, and I am wanting to transfer some data between a few activities. So, to do so, I created a class that has a method for me to get a result that I require in another activity. (NOTE : The name `viewmodel` of the class is not related to the android's ViewModel. It was just a mistake from my side naming it like that.)

Error Message :

```
   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.taskmasterv3, PID: 19537
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=20, result=-1, data=Intent { cmp=com.example.taskmasterv3/.TaskInfo (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.taskmasterv3/com.example.taskmasterv3.TaskInfo}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.File android.content.Context.getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5209)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5250)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2242)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8004)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:631)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:978)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.File android.content.Context.getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:370)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:316)
        at com.example.taskmasterv3.DBHelper.getdata(DBHelper.java:107)
        at com.example.taskmasterv3.MyViewModel.timeIntFinder(MyViewModel.java:22)
        at com.example.taskmasterv3.TaskInfo.onActivityResult(TaskInfo.java:441)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8316)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5202)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5250) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2242) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:245) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8004) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:631) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:978)
```

Code for Sqlite Database Class :

```
package com.example.taskmasterv3;



import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "Subtaskdata.db", null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL("create Table Subtaskdata(subtaskname TEXT primary key, prihigh INTEGER, primed INTEGER, prilow INTEGER, timemore INTEGER, timemed INTEGER, timeless INTEGER, totalTime INTEGER, time INTEGER)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("drop Table if exists Userdetails");
    }


    public Boolean insertSubtaskData(String subtaskName, int prihigh, int primed, int prilow, int timemore, int timemed, int timeless, int totalTime, int time){
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put("subtaskname", subtaskName);
            contentValues.put("priHigh", prihigh);
            contentValues.put("priMed", primed);
            contentValues.put("priLow", prilow);
            contentValues.put("timeMore", timemore);
            contentValues.put("timeMed", timemed);
            contentValues.put("timeLess", timeless);
            contentValues.put("totalTime", totalTime);
            contentValues.put("time", time);


            long result = db.insert("Subtaskdata", null, contentValues);
            if (result < 0){
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            } }



    public Boolean updateSubtaskData(String subtaskName, int prihigh, int primed, int prilow, int timemore, int timemed, int timeless,int totalTime, int time){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("subtaskname", subtaskName);
        contentValues.put("prihigh", prihigh);
        contentValues.put("primed", primed);
        contentValues.put("prilow", prilow);
        contentValues.put("timemore", timemore);
        contentValues.put("timemed", timemed);
        contentValues.put("timeless", timeless);
        contentValues.put("totalTime", totalTime);
        contentValues.put("time", time);

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("Select * from Subtaskdata where subtaskname = ?", new String[]{subtaskName});
        if (cursor.getCount()> 0){
        long result = db.update("Subtaskdata", contentValues, "name=?", new String[]{subtaskName});
        if (result== -1){
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        } }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }}






    public Boolean deletedata(String subtaskName){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("Select * from Subtaskdata where subtaskname = ?", new String[]{subtaskName});
        if (cursor.getCount()> 0){
            long result = db.delete("Subtaskdata","subtaskname=?", new String[]{subtaskName});
            if (result == -1){
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            } }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }}




        public Cursor getdata (){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("Select * from Subtaskdata", null);
        return cursor;
        }

        public void deleteAll(){

        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete("Subtaskdata", null, null);
        db.execSQL("delete from "+ "Subtaskdata");
        db.close();



        }








}
```

Code for Activity :

```
package com.example.taskmasterv3;


public class TaskInfo extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Declaring variables
    EditText etWorkingHours, etWorkingMinutes, etTaskName, etWorkingMins, etWorkinghrs, etSubtaskName;
    Button btnNewSubtask;
    Button btnSaveTaskName;
    Button btnProceed;
    ImageView ivLeft, ivRight;
    TextView tvBreakTime;
    TextView tvTaskName;
    int breaktime = 10;
    final int ENTER_SUBTASK = 20;
    final int EDIT_SUBTASK = 40;
    ListView lvSubtasks;
    ArrayList<subtask> subtaskList = new ArrayList<>();
    ScrollView scrollView;
    TaskSummaryViewModel viewModel;
    String taskName;
    boolean NpriHigh;
    boolean NpriMed;
    boolean NpriLow;
    boolean NtimeMore;
    boolean NtimeMed;
    boolean NtimeLess;
    DBHelper dbHelper;
    String subtname;
    String pri;
    String time;
    int timeConstant;









    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_task_info);






        



        tvTaskName.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        if (tvTaskName.getText().equals(""))
        {
            tvTaskName.setClickable(false);
        }
        else
        {
            tvTaskName.setClickable(true);
        }



// Code for the left right arrows along with break duration
        ivRight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (breaktime >= 10 && breaktime < 60)
                {breaktime += 5;
                    String time = breaktime + "";
                    tvBreakTime.setText(time);}

                else
                {
                    String time = breaktime + "";
                    tvBreakTime.setText(time);
                }
            }
        });

        ivLeft.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (breaktime > 10 && breaktime <= 60)
                {
                    breaktime -= 5;
                    String time = breaktime + "";
                    tvBreakTime.setText(time);}

                else
                {
                    String time = breaktime + "";
                    tvBreakTime.setText(time);
                }
            }
        });


        btnNewSubtask.setEnabled(false);
        btnSaveTaskName.setEnabled(false);

        //save button enabler when task name is written

        etTaskName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }



            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                btnSaveTaskName.setEnabled(!TextUtils.isEmpty(s.toString().trim()));
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });




        btnSaveTaskName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tvTaskName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                tvTaskName.setText(etTaskName.getText().toString().toUpperCase().trim());
                etTaskName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btnSaveTaskName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btnNewSubtask.setEnabled(true);

            }
        });


        tvTaskName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String tasksname = tvTaskName.getText().toString().trim();
                tvTaskName.setText("");
                etTaskName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                etTaskName.setText(tasksname);
                btnSaveTaskName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });



        btnNewSubtask.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent i2 = new Intent(TaskInfo.this, SubtaskActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(i2, ENTER_SUBTASK);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.slide_out_up);

            }
        });


        // THE DATABASE PART


        btnProceed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {










                if (etWorkingHours.getText().toString().isEmpty())
                {
                    etWorkingHours.setText("0");
                }
                if (etWorkingMinutes.getText().toString().isEmpty())
                {
                    etWorkingMinutes.setText("0");
                }
                if (etWorkinghrs.getText().toString().isEmpty())
                {
                    etWorkinghrs.setText("0");
                }
                if (etWorkingMins.getText().toString().isEmpty())
                {
                    etWorkingMins.setText("0");
                }

                int working_hours = Integer.parseInt(etWorkinghrs.getText().toString().trim());
                int working_minutes = Integer.parseInt(etWorkingMins.getText().toString().trim());
                int without_break_hours = Integer.parseInt(etWorkingHours.getText().toString().trim());
                int without_break_minutes = Integer.parseInt(etWorkingMinutes.getText().toString().trim());




                if (etWorkingHours.getText().toString().isEmpty() || etWorkingMinutes.getText().toString().isEmpty() || etWorkinghrs.getText().toString().isEmpty() || etWorkingMins.getText().toString().isEmpty())
                {
                    Toast.makeText(TaskInfo.this, "Field cannot be empty, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
                else
                {
                    if (working_hours != 0)
                    {
                        if (working_hours > without_break_hours)
                        {
                            int breaktime = Integer.parseInt(tvBreakTime.getText().toString());
                            Intent intent = new Intent(TaskInfo.this, TaskSummary.class);
                            intent.putExtra("working_hours", working_hours);
                            intent.putExtra("working_minutes", working_minutes);
                            intent.putExtra("without_break_hours", without_break_hours);
                            intent.putExtra("without_break_minutes", without_break_minutes);
                            intent.putExtra("break_duration", breaktime);
                            intent.putExtra("subtaskname", taskName);
                            intent.putExtra("priigh", NpriHigh);
                            intent.putExtra("primed", NpriMed);
                            intent.putExtra("prilow", NpriLow);
                            intent.putExtra("timemore", NtimeMore);
                            intent.putExtra("timemed", NtimeMed);
                            intent.putExtra("timeless", NtimeLess);
                            intent.putExtra("timeconstant", timeConstant);
                            startActivity(intent);

                        }

                        if (working_hours == without_break_hours){

                            if (working_minutes >= without_break_minutes){
                                int breaktime = Integer.parseInt(tvBreakTime.getText().toString());
                                Intent intent = new Intent(TaskInfo.this, TaskSummary.class);
                                intent.putExtra("working_hours", working_hours);
                                intent.putExtra("working_minutes", working_minutes);
                                intent.putExtra("without_break_hours", without_break_hours);
                                intent.putExtra("without_break_minutes", without_break_minutes);
                                intent.putExtra("break_duration", breaktime);
                                intent.putExtra("subtaskname", taskName);
                                intent.putExtra("priigh", NpriHigh);
                                intent.putExtra("primed", NpriMed);
                                intent.putExtra("prilow", NpriLow);
                                intent.putExtra("timemore", NtimeMore);
                                intent.putExtra("timemed", NtimeMed);
                                intent.putExtra("timeless", NtimeLess);
                                intent.putExtra("timeconstant", timeConstant);



                                startActivity(intent);

                            }

                            if (working_minutes < without_break_minutes){

                                Toast.makeText(TaskInfo.this, "Invalid Time Entered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }



                        }

                        if (working_hours < without_break_hours){
                            Toast.makeText(TaskInfo.this, "Invalid Time Entered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }

                    if (working_hours == 0){

                        if (without_break_hours == 0)
                        {

                            if (working_minutes >= without_break_minutes){
                                int breaktime = Integer.parseInt(tvBreakTime.getText().toString());
                                Intent intent = new Intent(TaskInfo.this, TaskSummary.class);
                                intent.putExtra("working_hours", working_hours);
                                intent.putExtra("working_minutes", working_minutes);
                                intent.putExtra("without_break_hours", without_break_hours);
                                intent.putExtra("without_break_minutes", without_break_minutes);
                                intent.putExtra("break_duration", breaktime);
                                intent.putExtra("subtaskname", taskName);
                                intent.putExtra("prihigh", NpriHigh);
                                intent.putExtra("primed", NpriMed);
                                intent.putExtra("prilow", NpriLow);
                                intent.putExtra("timemore", NtimeMore);
                                intent.putExtra("timemed", NtimeMed);
                                intent.putExtra("timeless", NtimeLess);
                                intent.putExtra("timeconstant", timeConstant);
                                startActivity(intent);

                            }

                            if (working_minutes < without_break_minutes){

                                Toast.makeText(TaskInfo.this, "Invalid Time Entered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }

                        }

                        if (without_break_hours != 0)
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(TaskInfo.this, "Invalid Time Entered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }










            }
        });


        //Applying the max min thing for which the class InputFilterMinMax is defined
        etWorkingHours.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilterMinMax("0", "24")});
        etWorkingMinutes.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilterMinMax("0", "59")});

        etWorkinghrs.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilterMinMax("0", "24")});
        etWorkingMins.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilterMinMax("0", "59")});


    }




// This is where I try to implement the executer :


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == ENTER_SUBTASK)
        {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {

                SubtaskAdapter adapter = new SubtaskAdapter(this, subtaskList);
                assert data != null;
                String subtaskName = data.getStringExtra("subtaskName");
                boolean priHigh = data.getBooleanExtra("priHigh", false);
                boolean priMed = data.getBooleanExtra("priMed", false);
                boolean priLow = data.getBooleanExtra("priLow", false);
                boolean timeMore = data.getBooleanExtra("timeMore", false);
                boolean timeMed = data.getBooleanExtra("timeMed", false);
                boolean timeLess = data.getBooleanExtra("timeLess", false);
                int time = data.getIntExtra("time", 1);



                lvSubtasks.setAdapter(adapter);
                subtask subtask = new subtask(subtaskName, priHigh, priMed, priLow, timeMore, timeMed, timeLess, time);
                subtaskList.add(subtask);
                adapter.addANewSubTask(subtask);
                MyViewModel myViewModel = new MyViewModel();
                timeConstant = myViewModel.timeIntFinder(subtaskList);

                taskName = subtaskName;
                NpriHigh = priHigh;
                NpriMed = priMed;
                NpriLow = priLow;
                NtimeLess = timeLess;
                NtimeMed = timeMed;
                NtimeMore = timeMore;


            }



            boolean delete = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("deleted", false);
            if (delete){

            }








        }


    }









}
```

Code for Class :

```
package com.example.taskmasterv3;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;

import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyViewModel  {

    int timeInt;
    int totalTime;
    int timeConstant;
    DBHelper dbHelper;
    Context context;


    public int timeIntFinder(ArrayList<subtask> list) {

        dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
        Cursor cursor = dbHelper.getdata();

        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){

            timeInt += list.get(i).getTime();

        }

        while (cursor.moveToNext()){

            totalTime = cursor.getInt(7);
            timeConstant = totalTime / timeInt;

        }
       return timeConstant;

    }






}
```

Code for activity where I want the data :

```
package com.example.taskmasterv3;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

public class TaskSummary extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView lvTaskList;
    TextView tvBreak, tvBreakAfterEvery, txt1, txt2, text1, hmm;
    TextView break_duration_mins;
    ArrayList<SubtaskPartTwo> subtaskList = new ArrayList<>();
    //String subtname;
    //String pri;
    //String time;
    int working_hours;
    int working_minutes;
    int totalTime;
    DBHelper dbHelper;
    int timeInts;
    int timeConstant;
    int answer;





    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.tasksummary, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        dbHelper.deleteAll();

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.restore) {
            Intent inti = new Intent(this, TaskInfo.class);
            startActivity(inti);

        }



        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_task_summary);


        MyViewModel myViewModel = new MyViewModel();








        lvTaskList = findViewById(R.id.lvTaskList);
        tvBreak = findViewById(R.id.tvBreak);
        tvBreakAfterEvery = findViewById(R.id.tvBreakAfterEvery);
        txt1 = findViewById(R.id.txt1);
        txt2 = findViewById(R.id.txt2);
        break_duration_mins = findViewById(R.id.break_duration_mins);
        text1 = findViewById(R.id.text1);
        hmm = findViewById(R.id.hmm);
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);

        working_hours = getIntent().getIntExtra("working_hours", 1);
        working_minutes = getIntent().getIntExtra("working_minutes", 0);
        timeConstant = getIntent().getIntExtra("timeconstant", 1);
        int alol = working_hours * 60;
        int blol = working_minutes;
        totalTime = alol + blol;
        double without_break_hours = getIntent().getIntExtra("without_break_hours", 1);
        double without_break_minutes = getIntent().getIntExtra("without_break_minutes", 0);
        double break_duration = getIntent().getIntExtra("break_duration", 20);
        String a = working_hours + " h";
        txt1.setText(a);
        String b = working_minutes + " m";
        break_duration_mins.setText(b);
        String c = break_duration + " m";
        txt2.setText(c);



        //Mathematics

        double g = working_hours * 100;
        double h = g + working_minutes;
        double i = h + break_duration;
        double j = i / 60;
        double p = (int) j;
        double q = j - p;
        double r = q * 60;

        without_break_hours = p;
        without_break_minutes = r;

        String d = without_break_hours + " h";
        String e = without_break_minutes + " m";

        text1.setText(d);
        hmm.setText(e);





        Cursor res = dbHelper.getdata();
        SubtaskDetailAdapter adapter = new SubtaskDetailAdapter(this, subtaskList);
        lvTaskList.setAdapter(adapter);




        while (res.moveToNext() && res != null){




            SubtaskPartTwo subtaskPartTwo = new SubtaskPartTwo(res.getString(0), res.getInt(1), res.getInt(2), res.getInt(3), res.getInt(4), res.getInt(5), res.getInt(6), 0, res.getInt(8), totalTime, timeConstant);
            //subtaskList.add(subtaskPartTwo);

            adapter.addANewSubTask(subtaskPartTwo);
        }



    }



// method from data transfer interface



}
```

Comment: Please post full log details to find out error accurately

Comment: @Udhaya okay, sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay here is your solution,
In your `MyViewModel.java` you have initialized `DBHelper` by passing a `Context`'s object which is null. So modify your MyViewModel as

**Option 1:**

```
package com.example.taskmasterv3;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;

import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyViewModel  {

    int timeInt;
    int totalTime;
    int timeConstant;
    DBHelper dbHelper;


    public int timeIntFinder(ArrayList<subtask> list,Context context) {

        dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
        Cursor cursor = dbHelper.getdata();

        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){

            timeInt += list.get(i).getTime();
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            totalTime = cursor.getInt(7);
            timeConstant = totalTime / timeInt;
        }
        return timeConstant;
    }
}
```

and in ActivityCode at `onActivityResult` change

`timeConstant = myViewModel.timeIntFinder(subtaskList);`

to

`timeConstant = myViewModel.timeIntFinder(subtaskList,this);`

**Option 2:**

Passing context in the constructor

Add constructor with context as a parameter for MyViewModel

```
public class MyViewModel  {

int timeInt;
int totalTime;
int timeConstant;
DBHelper dbHelper;
Context context;

public MyViewModel(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}

public int timeIntFinder(ArrayList<subtask> list) {

    dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
    Cursor cursor = dbHelper.getdata();

    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){

        timeInt += list.get(i).getTime();
    }
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        totalTime = cursor.getInt(7);
        timeConstant = totalTime / timeInt;
    }
    return timeConstant;
  }
}
```

now wherever you have initialized MyViewModel pass valid context.

Comment: This does work. Thanks. The app doesn't crash now. Even though the formula I implemented (with the for loops) doesn't work, that's for me to take care of ig. Thanks for the help :)